# Difficulties with understanding sockets in a TCP server-client exercise

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to learn how sockets and TCP server-client implementation in c works, and I'm doing an exercise involving sending and reading information between the server and the client. The exercise in question involves a travel agency that has acts as the server, which receives requests for tickets, then sends back to the client if it was accepted or declined.
Problem is i keep getting errors and don't know why so any help would be appreciated.
Server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include<time.h>
#define PORT 8080
#define SA struct sockaddr
/**************************************************/
struct Flights{
    int flight_id;
    char from_city[50];
    char to_city[50];
    int available_seats;
    int price;
    int sinolo;
    int apotixia;
    int epitixia;
}flight[10];

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, connfd, len;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddress, cli;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&servaddress, sizeof(servaddress));
    servaddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddress.sin_port = htons(8080);
    bind(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddress, sizeof(servaddress));
   listen( sockfd, 5 );
   len = sizeof(cli);
   connfd = accept(sockfd, (SA*)&cli, &len);
    if (connfd < 0) {
        printf("server accept failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("server accept the client...\n");
    int i;
    int tbuff[420];
    int p1buff[420];
    int p2buff[420];
    int p3buff[420];
    char buff[420];
    int n;
    int price1=0;
    int price2=0;
    int price3=0;
    int tickets;
    int pricetot=0;
    int id1;
    int id2;
    int id3;
    int request1=0;
    int request2=0;
    int request3=0;
    int epitixia=0;
    int sinolo=0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    strcpy(flight[0].from_city, "Athens");
    strcpy(flight[0].to_city, "Vathi");
    flight[0].flight_id = 1000;
    flight[0].price = 200;
    flight[0].available_seats = rand()%5+1;
    flight[0].sinolo=0;
    flight[0].apotixia=0;
    flight[0].epitixia=0;
    strcpy(flight[1].from_city, "Chania");
    strcpy(flight[1].to_city, "Athens");
    flight[1].flight_id = 900;
    flight[1].price = 150;
    flight[1].available_seats = rand()%5+1;
    flight[1].sinolo=0;
    flight[1].apotixia=0;
    flight[1].epitixia=0;
    strcpy(flight[2].from_city, "Thessaloniki");
    strcpy(flight[2].to_city, "Athens");
    flight[2].flight_id = 800;
    flight[2].price = 300;
    flight[2].available_seats = rand()%5+1;
    flight[2].sinolo=0;
    flight[2].apotixia=0;
    flight[2].epitixia=0;
    strcpy(flight[3].from_city, "Thessaloniki");
    strcpy(flight[3].to_city, "Vathi");
    flight[3].flight_id = 700;
    flight[3].price = 200;
    flight[3].available_seats = rand()%5+1;
    flight[3].sinolo=0;
    flight[3].apotixia=0;
    flight[3].epitixia=0;
    strcpy(flight[4].from_city, "Athens");
    strcpy(flight[4].to_city, "Chania");
    flight[4].flight_id = 600;
    flight[4].price = 400;
    flight[4].available_seats = rand()%5+1;
    flight[4].sinolo=0;
    flight[4].apotixia=0;
    flight[4].epitixia=0;
    strcpy(flight[5].from_city, "Athens");
    strcpy(flight[5].to_city, "Alexandroupoli");
    flight[5].flight_id = 500;
    flight[5].price = 300;
    flight[5].available_seats = rand()%5+1;
    flight[5].sinolo=0;
    flight[5].apotixia=0;
    flight[5].epitixia=0;
    strcpy(flight[6].from_city, "Alexandroupoli");
    strcpy(flight[6].to_city, "Vathi");
    flight[6].flight_id = 400;
    flight[6].price = 250;
    flight[6].available_seats = rand()%5+1;
    flight[6].sinolo=0;
    flight[6].apotixia=0;
    flight[6].epitixia=0;
    strcpy(flight[7].from_city, "Alexandroupoli");
    strcpy(flight[7].to_city, "Athens");
    flight[7].flight_id = 300;
    flight[7].price = 200;
    flight[7].available_seats = rand()%5+1;
    flight[7].sinolo=0;
    flight[7].apotixia=0;
    flight[7].epitixia=0;
    strcpy(flight[8].from_city, "Vathi");
    strcpy(flight[8].to_city, "Alexandroupoli");
    flight[8].flight_id = 200;
    flight[8].price = 400;
    flight[8].available_seats = rand()%5+1;
    flight[8].sinolo=0;
    flight[8].apotixia=0;
    flight[8].epitixia=0;
    strcpy(flight[9].from_city, "Thessaloniki");
    strcpy(flight[9].to_city, "Alexandroupoli");
    flight[9].flight_id = 100;
    flight[9].price = 150;
    flight[9].available_seats = rand()%5+1;
    flight[9].sinolo=0;
    flight[9].apotixia=0;
    flight[9].epitixia=0;
    printf("Flight id: %d, Available seats: %d\n",flight[i].flight_id,flight[i].available_seats);
    printf("From: %s, To: %s\n",flight[i].from_city,flight[i].to_city);
    printf("Price: %d\n\n",flight[i].price);
    int count=0;
    while(count<5)
    {
            sleep(1);
            read(connfd, tickets, sizeof(tickets));
            read(connfd, id1, sizeof(id1));
            for (int t=0;t<tickets;t++){
                if (t==0){
                    for(int x=0;x<10;x++){
                        if(id1 == flight[x].flight_id){
                            if(flight[x].available_seats-1>=0){
                                flight[x].available_seats=flight[x].available_seats-1;
                                flight[x].epitixia++;
                                flight[x].sinolo++;
                                sinolo++;
                                epitixia++;
                                price1=flight[x].price;
                                x=10;
                                pricetot=pricetot+price1;
                                request1=1;
                                request2=0;
                                request3=0;
                               write(connfd, request1, sizeof(request1));
                               write(connfd, price1, sizeof(price1));
                            }
                            else{
                            request1=2;
                            request2=0;
                            request3=0;
                            flight[x].apotixia++;
                            flight[x].sinolo++;
                            sinolo++;
                            write(connfd, request1, sizeof(request1));
                            x=10;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (t==1){
                        read(connfd, id2, sizeof(p2buff));
                        for(int x=0;x<10;x++){
                                if(id2 == flight[x].flight_id){
                                    if(flight[x].available_seats-1>=0){
                                    flight[x].available_seats=flight[x].available_seats-1;
                                    flight[x].epitixia++;
                                    flight[x].sinolo++;
                                    sinolo++;
                                    epitixia++;
                                    price2=flight[x].price;
                                    x=10;
                                    pricetot=pricetot+price2;
                                    request2=1;
                                    write(connfd, request2, sizeof(request2));
                                    write(connfd, price2, sizeof(price2));
                                    }
                                else{
                                request2=2;
                                write(connfd, request2, sizeof(request2));
                                flight[x].apotixia++;
                                flight[x].sinolo++;
                                x=10;
                                sinolo++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                else if (t==2){
                    read(connfd, id3, sizeof(p3buff));
                    for(int x=0;x<10;x++){
                        if(id3 == flight[x].flight_id){
                            if(flight[x].available_seats-1>=0){
                                flight[x].available_seats=flight[x].available_seats-1;
                                flight[x].epitixia++;
                                flight[x].sinolo++;
                                sinolo++;
                                epitixia++;
                                price3=flight[x].price;
                                pricetot=pricetot+price3;
                                x=10;
                                request3=1;
                                write(connfd, request3, sizeof(request3));
                                write(connfd, price3, sizeof(price3));
                            }
                            else{
                            request3=2;
                            write(connfd, request3, sizeof(request3));
                            flight[x].apotixia++;
                            flight[x].sinolo++;
                            x=10;
                            sinolo++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        close(sockfd);
        sleep(1);
        count++;
        }
    }
        for(int h=0;h<10;h++){
        printf("From: %s, To: %s\nTotal:%d, Successes: %d, Failures: %d Remaining Seats %d\n\n",flight[h].from_city,flight[h].to_city,flight[h].sinolo,flight[h].epitixia,flight[h].apotixia,flight[h].available_seats);
        }
        printf("Profit: %d, Total: %d, Successes: %d\n",pricetot,sinolo,epitixia);
    return 0;
}

Client.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include<time.h>
#define PORT 8080
#define SA struct sockaddr
/**************************************************/
int main()
{
    int tickets;
    int id1;
    int id2;
    int id3;
    int request1;
    int request2;
    int request3;
    int price1;
    int price2;
    int price3;
    int sockfd,connfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddress, cli;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&servaddress, sizeof(servaddress));
    servaddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddress.addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    servaddress.port = htons(8080);
    if (connect(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddress, sizeof(servaddress)) != 0) {
        printf("connection with the server failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("connected to the server..\n");
        while(1)
        {
            srand(time(NULL) ^ (getpid()));
            tickets=rand()%3+1;
            printf("number of tickets %d\n",tickets);
            id1=(rand()%10);
            id1++;
            printf("Id of flight 1 is %d\n",id1);
            write(sockfd, tickets, sizeof(tickets));
            write(sockfd, id1, sizeof(id1));
            if (tickets==2){
             id2=(rand()%10);
             id2++;
             write(sockfd, id2, sizeof(id2));
            }
            else if (tickets==3){
             id2=(rand()%10);
             id2++;
             printf("Id of flight 2 is %d\n",id2);
             if(write(sockfd, id2, sizeof(id2));
             id3=(rand()%10);
             id3++;
             printf("Id of flight 3 is %d\n",id3);
             write(sockfd, id3, sizeof(id3));
            }
            read(sockfd, request1, sizeof(request1));
            if (request1==1){
                printf("The request for flight %d, was successfull\n",id1);
                read(sockfd, price1, sizeof(price1));
                printf("The price of the requested flight was %d euro\n",price1);
            }
            else if(request1==2){
                printf("The request for flight %d, was unsuccessfull,not enough available seats\n",id1);
            }
            if (tickets==2 || tickets==3){
                read(sockfd, request2, sizeof(request2));
                if (request2==1){
                    printf("The request for flight %d, was successfull\n",id2);
                    read(sockfd, price2, sizeof(price2));
                    printf("The price of the requested flight was %d euro\n",price2);
                }
                else if(request2==2){
                    printf("The request for flight %d, was unsuccessfull,not enough available seats\n",id2);
                }
                if (tickets==3){
                    read(sockfd, request3, sizeof(request3));
                    if (request3==1){
                     printf("The request for flight %d, was successfull\n",id3);
                     read(sockfd, price3, sizeof(price3));
                     printf("The price of the requested flight was %d euro\n",price3);
                    }
                    else if(request3==2){
                        printf("The request for flight %d, was unsuccessfull,not enough available seats\n",id3);
                    }
                }
            }
            close(sockfd);
            break;
        }
            return(0);
}
```

errors I'm getting is this

```
main.c:151:26: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘read’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  151 |             read(connfd, tickets, sizeof(tickets));
      |                          ^~~~~~~
      |                          |
      |                          int
In file included from main.c:3:
/usr/include/unistd.h:360:38: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
  360 | extern ssize_t read (int __fd, void *__buf, size_t __nbytes) __wur;
      |                                ~~~~~~^~~~~
```

for all the reads and writes.

Comment: "Problem is i keep getting errors ...." It could be helpful if you told what erors you get

Comment: main.c:151:26: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘read’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  151 |             read(connfd, tickets, sizeof(tickets));
      |                          ^~~~~~~
      |                          |
      |                          int
In file included from main.c:3:
/usr/include/unistd.h:360:38: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
  360 | extern ssize_t read (int __fd, void *__buf, size_t __nbytes) __wur;
      |                                ~~~~~~^~~~~

Comment: Edit the question and add that info

Comment: `int tickets;` will never be a void pointer as `read` expects. The warning say it all.

Comment: you are passing an integer to a function that expects a void pointer

Comment: you need to read https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html

Comment: I haven't checked all your code but perhaps you want: `read(connfd, tickets, sizeof(tickets));` --> `read(connfd, &tickets, sizeof(tickets));` but if this is something being received over a network connect you need to take care of endianess....

Comment: now i'm getting an error for this line
servaddress.addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
error: ‘struct sockaddr_in’ has no member named ‘addr’

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what TCP is.

TCP passes a stream of bytes from one point to another. The only gurantees are

- the bytes arrive in the same order they were sent
- the bytes are only sent one time

Whats not guranteed is that you receive in the same size chunk that you send. YOU might send 20 bytes and receive 4 lots of 5 characters.

This means you have to invent a wire protocol. IN particular you need to know how long a messga eis going to be so you can loop until you have received it all.

Second there are only bytes, you have to marshal numbers, strings etc into bytes and back again.

This is why you are getting compile errors.

```
   read(connfd, tickets, sizeof(tickets));
```

the second parameter must be a bytes buffer. You need to take those bytes and rebuilt the int, taking into account the byte ordering. But more importantly taking into account that this read might not return all the bytes, you need to loop till you have everything.

I would strongly recommend not having a binary protocol, which is what you have right now. I would convert the ticket request to a string (json maybe or some plain text ), send the whole string in one go , with a length prepended to it then read it all in one go and parse it.

Either way your code needs to have something like this in is

```
  int length = read_length() ;// from socket
   int offset = 0;
   while(length > 0)
   {
        int read = read(socket, &buffer[offset], length);
    
        offset+= read;
        length -= read;

   }
```

this is a sketch, not compilable code.

The point is you must know how much data you need and then keep reading till you get it all.

YOu could have (if you keep binary), a function like this

```
int readInt(){
{
      int length = 4; // assuming 4 byte ints
      int result;
      char *resBuff = (char*)&result;
      int offset = 0;
      while(length > 0)
      {
        int read = read(socket, &resBuff[offset], length);
        offset+= read;
        length -= read;
       }

 }
```

this will read a binary int off the wire assuming the same endianness.